# Using .map to map an array of one class to an array of another

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I'm new to Swift, and am trying to get my head around using .map. My understanding is that the behaviour is similar to that of Javascript, but maybe I'm not nailing the Swift syntax correctly?

I've created a public Array of my custom class `CustomItem` (which is a subclass of the type coming back in the response):

```
public var availableItems: [CustomItem] = []

public static func getAvailableItems(id: String, completion: (items: [CustomItem]) -> ()) -> Void {
    DataConnector.getRelated(type: "users", id: id, relationship: "available") { (response) -> Void in
        availableItems = (response.data?.map { return $0 as! CustomItem })!
        completion(items: availableItems)
    }
}
```

When I do a `po response.data.map { return $0 }` in the console with a breakpoint after the response is received, I get:

```
(lldb) po response.data.map { return $0 }
▿ Optional([<AnSDK.RemoteDataObject: 0x7f8a0b9c16b0>])
  ▿ Some : 1 elements
    ▿ [0] : < AnSDK.RemoteDataObject: 0x7f8a0b9c16b0>
```

So it definitely seems that part works, but when I try to cast the data object to `CustomItem` class, I get:

```
Could not cast value of type 'AnSDK.RemoteDataObject' (0x100abbda0) to 'Project.CustomItem' (0x100882c60).
```

Here's my `CustomItem` class just in case:

```
import AnSDK

public class CustomItem: RemoteDataObject {
    var displayName: String = ""
    var value: Float = 0.0
    var owner: User?
}
```

If I don't use the ! to force downcast, I get:

```
RemoteDataObject is not convertible to CustomItem [...]
```

... in the compiler.

Comment: You aren't able to cast RemoteDataObject to a CustomItem because it was never a CustomItem in the first place.  
You can always upcast something but downcasting will only work if the object was originally the subclass.  
Ben's comment is a solution that should fit your purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'm really just restating Ben Gottlieb's answer here, but hopefully a bit clearer since I believe some readers were confused by his attempt.)

The message seems fairly clear. You've received an array of `AnSDK.RemoteDataObject`. As best I can tell from your output, that is the actual class of the objects. You can't just say "it's really this subclass of RDO" unless it *really is that subclass*. Looking at your code, that seems unlikely. Somewhere in `AnSDK` it would have to construct a `CustomItem` and then just happen to return it as a `RemoteDataObject`. That doesn't appear to be what's happening inside of `getRelated`. Given your code, I doubt `AnSDK` knows anything about `CustomItem`, so how would it have constructed one?

There are numerous ways to fix this depending on what the types really are and how they interact. Ben's solution is one, which basically creates a copy of the object (though in that case, there's no particular reason for `CustomItem` to be a subclass of `RDO`, and probably shouldn't be.)

If you just want to add methods to `RemoteDataObject`, you can do that with extensions. You don't need to create a subclass.

Comment: Alright, that makes more sense. I think for semantics and visible representation, I'd like to create a copy of the object into the new class - RDO is a very basic class of object, and I'd like to create several more specific ones for use throughout the app. If you could provide an example of how to properly create that copy, I'd be grateful!